# DC motor fails to operate at solar panel even though the voltage is correct

Tags: dc-motor, solar-cell

I have several small (1.5 - 6V) DC motors. If I hook up one or two 1.5V batteries in series to any of the motors, the motor runs. I also have several small solar panels that produce from 2 to 6 Volts maximum. When I hook any of the panels to a motor, the motor does not run. Why is that?

Comment: Watt output must exceed motor demand. is it?  What is Voc/Isc ? and DCR of motor?

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the specifications of the panels.

Comment: What Ayush says. POWER the panel provides MUST exceed power motor needs. Measure panel open cct voltage Voc in full sun. Measure panel current Isc when short circuited into a meter mA range in full sun. Panel power output Pmp ~~~= Voc x Isc x 70%.

Answer (score 3):

Check the voltage supplied by the solar cell panel with a motor connected. It may not be producing the required voltage when loaded. Moreover, for the motor to start rotating there is a minimum amount of current needed. To resolve this problem you might be needing more panels in parallel combination or a motor of lower wattage.

Comment: Don't explain or apologize. Just answer. It seems like you had the right idea.